# c - malloc not working for double type array

Tags: c, arrays, double, malloc

I'm trying to allocate memory for a double type array to use it with GNU Scientific Library.
The code in using for this is something like

```
double *x_i, *y_i, *x_e, *y_e, data[MAX_SIZE][2];
int n_i, n_e, n_data;
...
x_i = (double *)malloc(n_i * sizeof(double));
y_i = (double *)malloc(n_i * sizeof(double));
x_e = (double *)malloc(n_e * sizeof(double));
y_e = (double *)malloc(n_e * sizeof(double));
for (int i = 0; i < n_data; i++){
    if (data[i][1] > 0){
        x_e[i] = data[i][0];
        y_e[i] = data[i][1];
    }
    else{
        x_i[i] = data[i][0];
        y_i[i] = data[i][1];
    }
}
```

With n_i + n_e = n_data.

Apparently, `sizeof(x/y_e/i)` after malloc is 8, but should be arround `50*sizeof(double)`. The values attributed after the for loop to `x_e/i[i]` and `y_e/i[i]` are not consistent, they change as I change the order of attribution, sometimes returning `-nan`. Values of `data[][]`, `n_i`, `n_e` and `n_data` are consistent with I expect, and if I print `x_e/i[i]` and `y_e/i[i]` values inside the for loop they look correct, but outside that loop they change.

Thank you, and sorry if this is a redundant or bad formulated question.

Comment: `n_i, n_e, n_data` are uninitialized. In the code presented at least.

Comment: You also don't initialize all `x_i` or `x_e`. some of these cells are left untouched because of the if condition inside your loop. those might be your "inconsistent" -nan values, perhaps

Comment: Marcus, sizeof will return only sizes known in compiled time. Only fixed arrays will have sizeof return the "length" of the your array. since you are mallocing on runtime it won't be known in compile time. Even if it would be possible for a compiler to derive it, sizeof of a pointer will either 4/8 bytes according the platform, as @xing already mentioned.

Comment: malloc always "works". Programmers not. You should ask : what is wrong with my program instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because , malloc, sizeof, unitialized variables etc were discussed here 1000000 times. It was enough to use SO search engine.

Comment: @Aviv you did not understand my comment. It is not about technical detail, but about something else

Comment: The *size* of `x_i` doesn't change when you change its *value*. Your assignment after calling `malloc` only changes the value of `x_i` (to be the value returned by `malloc`).

Comment: @PeterJ_01, I'm sure the problem is in the program. I'm not complaining about malloc, just asking for help. Also, n_i, n_e and n_data are initialized in other part of the code (sorry about edits, having problems with cellphone)

Comment: @Marcus L. de Oliveira The title says something else. And some effort is required as well. If you debug your program step by step you would discover it in no time.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 sorry about that, will be paying more attention to that in future. Thanks for the warning :)

Comment: A do not warn anyone - but did you even try to find the solution? Have you read literally identical questions asked here?

Comment: Thanks everyone for your warnings and tips, will be trying to implement suggestions soon and write a feedback.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Yes, searched a lot, no only here on SO but in other places too. Tried to use calloc also, looked for different ways to do that but nothing worked. I finished the post asking for sorry if this is redundant, and reinforce that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to `sizeof(x/y_e/i)` actually returning `sizeof(double*)` (as other users have mentioned), your for-loop is incorrect:

If `n_i + n_e == n_data`, then you will always hit a case where attempting to access `x/y_e/i[i]` will take you out of bounds. To avoid this, you could keep track of `x/y_e`'s and `x/y_i`'s indices separately, perhaps like this:

```
int i_e = 0, i_i = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < n_data; i++){
    if (data[i][1] > 0){
        x_e[i_e] = data[i][0];
        y_e[i_e] = data[i][1];
        i_e++;
    }
    else{
        x_i[i_i] = data[i][0];
        y_i[i_i] = data[i][1];
        i_i++;
    }
}
```

By the end of the loop, you should find that `i_e + i_i == n_data` and that the values assigned to `x_e/i` and `y_e/i` are consistent.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I'll be trying that too.

Comment: Now I get home and read your answer paying full attention and it seemed so obvious. Everything is working now and I'm feeling stupid and happy at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: That's great! Glad we could help

Answer (score 1):

First, `sizeof(x_i)` with `x_i` being of type `double*` is the size of a pointer (probably `8` on your system), and not the size of the memory allocated. There is no way to get the size of the memory block to which a pointer points solely from the pointer.

Second, the "changing values" of the array that are not set in the loop are caused by having not initialized this portion of the array. Actually you yield undefined behaviour, most likely printing "garbage" when accessing these values. To overcome this, use `calloc` instead of `malloc`. `calloc` zero-initializes the memory block allocated, and according to IEEE standards, floating point values with all bits set to `0` represent the floating point value `0.0`:

```
x_i = calloc(n_i, sizeof(double));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, friend! I was initially using calloc, but inside a function, and the program was with the same behavior, probably due to some mistake I made. I'll be trying your suggestion soon. Thanks again!